How does Google Vertex AI Agent Builder Recomendation model Document update work?
I create an Agent Builder with App type Recommendations for Media content
All the data requirement is met and I am able to train the model
Data requirement
The model finishes training and is able to output prediction in the preview tab
Model Preview
The thing that I don't understand is when I try to update or delete some document in my data store
for example, document no.47941 was deleted from the data store and no longer exists in the data store
I confirm this by looking at the documents tab and this ID no longer exists and call the document from the API also no longer returns the data
Document Page
But the model somehow still returns this document back to the request
Model Preview Page
So it seems like the model is not connected to the data store in real-time and works with some data somewhere.
But I can't find any document mentioning this in the
https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/introduction?authuser=1
The only thing I found is that the document mentions to re-train the model some time to avoid model degrade.
Based on this link the model should not return any DELETED  or EXPIRED document
https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/reference/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.dataStores.servingConfigs/recommend
Recommend Filter Detail
But I have no clue how to check the status in the data store and I deleted the document it should be status DELETED anyway
I didn't create multiple data stores for the app and I didn't have any new branches or collections both are using the default
So my question if anyone knows is how does the model connect to the data store?
Is it only updating the document result if the model is retrained?
Or do I need to re-index the data store somehow for the model to get the updated data?
I have search around on the index topic also didn't find anything  useful
I searched and read around on the document but didn't find anything related to this.
Try to purge the data store but the model still returns data.
Ideally, i expect the model to be able to output the document based on whatever data exists in the data store so if it got deleted or updated it should not return anymore but somehow it return
